Been struggling to work out the chance of the community cards being dealt as a Royal Flush.
I know that 52C5 is the total number of different 5 carded hands in the game of poker and from this, a royal flush is a 1 in ~650000 occurrence. I am curious as to the chances of the community cards being a royal flush in a 5 handed game.
Given that 10 cards are removed when dealt as the hole cards to the table.
There are also 2 cards removed when a card is burnt after the turn and river.
These 12 cards when removed can not contain more than 3 suits of either ( A, K, Q, J or 10), otherwise there is zero chance of the community cards being a royal flush.
I have been struggling to get anywhere, this isn't a question on or test or suchlike just rather a little thought experiment I have been playing around with, if anyone is more adept at probability, I'd love for them to have a crack at his.
I am also curious if I am overcomplicating this, if so I would love to have it explained.
Is initially thought it could be  simply $$\frac{4}{(52C17)} $$
I realise this is likely in error as there are many combinations of the remaining 12 cards given that the royal flush is dealt to the community.

I think you are overcomplicating this. That other cards get pulled out of the deck first and in between doesn't matter... the deck is shuffled, so the five community cards are just five random cards like a five-card hand off the top would be. The probability of them being a royal flush is the same.

Is the probability not affected by the whereabouts of each card though? There have been many instances of televised royal flushes, and I even know 2 or 3 friends who have been dealt them. I have never seen a royal flush dealt as the community cards though.

@trawling The probability of the community cards being a royal flush is significantly lower than the probability of some player having a royal flush. Even with only two players, there are quite a few more ways for a player to have a royal flush than just it being on the board. I'm not sure how this is connected to your first sentence, though, or what your first sentence means.

Apologies, my english isn't great. I meant, the probability affected by the cards that have been dealt, more specifically, the order in which they are dealt now matters, pulling 5 cards off the top of a deck would give the 4/52C5 probability as most poker players are familiar with. Is there now a complexity added as before the community cards are dealt and during ( with burn cards), the remaining cards still have to contain at least a single suit of royal flush cards.

@trawling Ok, you have 52 card deck in a random order. Label them 1-52. The community cards are cards 12,13,14, 16, 18. (I'm assuming 5 players, 2 hole cards each + 1 burn, so the first card of the flop is 12). Why should the odds of cards 12,13,14,16,18 being a Royal flush be any different from 1,2,3,4,5?

Because depending on what card is dealt to the players and the burn, the odds of a royal flush changes. For example say I have a deck and remove 3 of the kings before I deal out 5 cards. Now there is only a single possible royal flush. Now say I deal out 20 cards all not being in a royal flush. The chance of a royal flush being dealt to the community is higher? The probability isn't just 4/52C5.

@trawling Yes, once you know what cards 1-11 are, of course the odds of 12,13,14,16,18 being a royal flush changes, depending on what the cards are. What does that have to do with the question, which as far as I can tell is about the prior odds of the board being a royal flush? Why are you assuming we know what the cards are when we don't?

The question was, what are the odds of a royal flush being dealt to the community given that 10 cards are dealt out and 2 cards are burnt. If it were to be 4/(40C5), none of the relevant cards can have been dealt to anyone or burnt. There is a chance they have been though and so the odds are not that simple no? The "burning" of cards also occurs during the dealing of the community cards.

@trawling Do we know anything about what cards were dealt/burnt?

No but that shouldn't matter, knowing what cards get dealt or not doesn't change anything as the question is about the initial odds of the community recieving a royal flush. Do you have a possible answer to the question?

@trawling The answer is 4 in 52 c5. (Why would it be 4 in 40 c5, that makes no sense?)

@trawling Like, how is this different from if we have two players playing 5 card draw, and we ask what the probability of player 1 having been dealt a royal flush? They get dealt a card, then player 2 gets dealt a card, then they get dealt another, and so on. They didn't get those cards "off the top" and if we know the cards player 2 got, it affects player 1 odds of a royal flush. Who cares? We don't know p2's cards or the cards in the rest of the deck. They could have any 5 cards at random. It's 4 in 52 choose 5. Similarly the board cards in holdem could be any 5 cards at random.
